# Locking a method until another is done

Tags: java, multithreading, locking

I have an external API I have to call that requires a validation token. The app calling the API will be threaded. Also, only 5 concurrent connections are allowed. I'm going to use a fixed thread pool for the connections, but I'm having an issue with figuring out how to handle an expired/invalid token. What I want to do is, when one thread encounters an expired token, prevent the other threads from acquiring the token until it has been refreshed. I'm thinking of using ReentrantLock to do this, but I'm not sure if my implementation is correct.

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
        new Thread(new LockTest()).start();
    }
}

public void testLock(String message) throws InterruptedException{ 
    try{
        getToken(message);

        /*
         * Use token here
         */
        Thread.sleep(1000);

        Random r = new Random();
        int num = r.nextInt((25-0) + 1);

        if(num == 1){ //testing only - exception thrown randomly.
            throw new Exception("Token Expired!");
        }

        System.out.println("Message: " +  message);

    }catch(Exception e){
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        awaitTokenRefresh = true;
        refreshToken(); 
    }
}

private void refreshToken() throws InterruptedException {
    lock.lock();
    try{
        System.out.println("Refreshing token...");
        Thread.sleep(2000l);
        System.out.println("Refreshed!");
        awaitTokenRefresh = false;
        awaitRefresh.signalAll();
    }
    finally{
        lock.unlock();
    }   
}

//test use case for salesforce token
private void getToken(String message) throws InterruptedException {
    lock.lock();
    try{
        while(awaitTokenRefresh){
            System.out.println(message + " waiting for token refresh...");
            awaitRefresh.await();
        }
    }
    finally{
        lock.unlock();
    }
}

public void run(){
    try {
        System.out.println("Starting thread...");
        testLock(Thread.currentThread().getName());
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Just for testing, I've put in some sleeps to mimic work being done. The main thing I don't know about is, when thread A unlocks inside of getToken() thread B enters, but we don't know if the token is invalid yet. So B could actually be getting a bad token that A has to find. Is there a good way to handle this? Or is the idea of using locks completely wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing I notice is that your code is not properly synchronized.  The exception handler in `testLock()` modifies shared variable `awaitTokenRefresh` at a point where that write is not ordered relative to other threads reading its value in `getToken()`.

> The main thing I don't know about is, when thread A unlocks inside of getToken() thread B enters, but we don't know if the token is invalid yet. So B could actually be getting a bad token that A has to find. Is there a good way to handle this? Or is the idea of using locks completely wrong?

I guess what you really want to avoid is unnecessary token refreshes when the current token becomes invalid.  Exactly one thread should refresh it; the others should simply wait for the refresh and then continue about their business.  The problem with your approach is that the threads have no good way to determine whether they are the first to detect the expiration, and so should take responsibility for refreshing.  And indeed that makes sense, because the concept of which thread does *anything* first is not always well defined in a multithreaded application.

Whether you use locks vs. synchronization is an implementation detail of relatively minor consequence.  The key is that you must have some shared state that tells threads whether the token they propose to refresh is in fact still current at all.  I might implement it something like this:

```
public class MyClass {
    private Object token = null;
    private final Object tokenMonitor = new Object();

    // ...

    private Object getToken() {
        synchronized (tokenMonitor) {
            if (token == null) {
                return refreshToken(null);
            } else {
                return token;
            }
        }
    }

    private Object refreshToken(Object oldToken) {
        synchronized (tokenMonitor) {
            if (token == oldToken) {  // test reference equality
                token = methodToPerformARefreshAndGenerateANewToken();
            }
            return token;
        }
    }

    // ...
}
```

The idea there is when it tries to refresh the token, each thread specifies *which* token it is trying to refresh.  A refresh is performed only if that is in fact the current token, and either way, the current token is returned.

You could use a `ReentrantLock` in place of my `tokenMonitor`, with locking and unlocking instead of synchronized blocks, but I much prefer plain synchronization when the scope is well contained, as in this case.  Among other things, it's safer -- when you leave a synchronized block, you leave it; there is no possibility of failing to release the relevant monitor.  The same cannot be said for lock objects.

Comment: I like synchronized statements better than locks anyway. They seem much cleaner and simpler. I'll give this a try.

Answer (score 0):

This actually looks a problem that can be solved with versioning:

```
public class LockTest {

    private int currentVersion = -1;
    private Object token = null;

    private synchronized int refreshToken(int requestorVersion) {
        if (requestorVersion == currentVersion) {
            try {
                //do the actual refresh
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                token = new Object();
                currentVersion++;
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
        }

        return currentVersion;
    }

    public VersionedToken takeToken() {
        if (currentVersion == -1) {
            refreshToken(-1);
        }

        return new VersionedToken(currentVersion);
    }

    public class VersionedToken {

        private int version;

        public VersionedToken(int version) {
            this.version = version;
        }

        private void refresh() {
            version = refreshToken(version);
        }

        private Object getToken() {
            return token;
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LockTest t = new LockTest();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            new Thread(() -> {
                VersionedToken vtoken = t.takeToken();
                Object token = vtoken.getToken();

                try {
                //do something with the token 
                }catch (Exception ex) {
                    //if token went bad - just refresh it and continue to work with it afterwords
                    vtoken.refresh();
                    token = vtoken.getToken();
                }
            }).start();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: This could work. The only problem is that there isn't an endpoint in the external API for testing if a token is good. I just have to use it and wait for an HTTP error.

Comment: @jordaniac89, please see my last edit, after taking the details you provided in the last comment into account I no longer think that RW lock is suitable.. versioning looks like a much better fit.